# DDMathParser create expression from NSString

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have an `NSString`:

n + (n - m)

Can I use DDMathParser for create an expression object.

For example I have base expression n + (n - m), but I need to have ability compare base expression n + (n - m) with an user expression e.g. (n - m) + n that typically the same as well.

Or is there alredy made solution how to compare two NSString considering signs and braces?

So I mean can I for example init two expressions with a string and then compare it like Expression1 = Expression2 using some method.

This is example how expressions have to look in parser

[image]

so this is the same struct and we can compare it using left and right node. of the tree. I am interesting to find out this solution that will parse string to expression tree. I think this solution was alredy made.

Comment: The strings are not equivalent (same chars in the same order), so a compare and an `-isEqualToString:` would fail.  NSString was not meant for mathematical equivalency.

Comment: yes I know it. I need a parser that can create tree from nsstring where leaf will be numbers and parent node will be signs, then I can compare this is expression I mean I can compare they structure. so in this case I will not care about order in which digital will be located. do you know what I mean?

Comment: you need to explain a bit more - what exactly do you desire - you want to compare the pattern? - what output do you need?

Comment: ok, i will explain. I have NSString object with math elements. These are numbers, signs and letters. So when I have string like this 5 + (5 - 3) that means I have an expression. Of course I can use method for NSString isEqualToString: for full compare two strings, but this is not my purpose. My purpose is compare two expressions. For example if I have expression 5 + (5 - 3) but user enter (5 - 3) + 5 in this case strings are not the same but expressions are the same. you see? thanks for response. I need some parser that can do it - create expressiom from NSSrting and comapre it.

Comment: Well, if you run it through DD, and it gives you an output of two NSNumbers, then surely you could just compare those, right?

Comment: i dont use DD honestly, but I think it can help me.

Comment: and I don't need compare the results. I just need compare struct

Comment: I have upadted questions with images, that shows which expression I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use DDMathParser to do this:

```
NSString *string = @"5 + (5 - 3)";
NSError *error = nil;
DDExpression *expression = [DDExpression expressionFromString:string error:&error];

if (expression) {
  NSLog(@"%@", expression)
} else {
  NSLog(@"%@", error);
}
```

DDMathParser does have some (rudimentary) support for [expression rewriting](https://github.com/davedelong/DDMathParser/wiki/Rewriting-Expressions), but other than that it'd be up to you to compare the expression trees yourself.