# Solving math using DDMathParser in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, ddmathparser

I'd like to use DDMathParser to solve a math problem. The top answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13260682/ddmathparser-create-expression-from-nsstring) StackOverflow question shows how, but it only solves it to the log. I'd like to get the answer as a string on an integer. The code `NSLog(@"%@", [math numberByEvaluatingString]);` also works, but it only prints it to the log.

What I'd like to do would be something like `answerText = @"%@", [math numberByEvaluatingString];`, where "math" is the string to evaluate, and "answerText" is the string to push the answer to. However, when I try to display the string in a label like `Label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:answerText];`, I get a sigabrt error. I'm not sure what's up. That code does not work at all with an integer.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [math numberByEvaluatingString]];
```

There is probably a better way to coerce it to a string, but I'm too lazy to go see what `numberByEvaluatingString` actually returns.

Answer (score 1):

The Objective-C version of DDMathParser returns an `NSNumber`. That means that in order to show it as the value in a textfield, you need to convert it to a string.

While using `+stringWithFormat:` would work, it's not technically *correct*. By using `+stringWithFormat:`, you're relying on the `-description` of the `NSNumber`, which may have information you don't want, or lack information that you do want.

The best way to "render" an `NSNumber` into an `NSString` suitable for human consumption is to use an `NSNumberFormatter`.